# How to prevent file wipe if an error occurs while writing to it?

Tags: java, android, file, fileoutputstream

This is an issue I have had in many applications.
I want to change the information inside a file, which has an outdated version.
In this instance, I am updating the file that records playlists after adding a song to a playlist. (For reference, I am creating an app for android.)

The problem is if I run this code:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
output.write(data.getBytes());
output.close();
```

And if an IOException occurs while trying to write to the file, the data is lost (since creating an instance of FileOutputStream empties the file). Is there a better method to do this, so if an IOException occurs, the old data remains intact? Or does this error only occur when the file is read-only, so I just need to check for that?

My only "work around" is to inform the user of the error, and give said user the correct data, which the user has to manually update. While this might work for a developer, there is a lot of issues that could occur if this happens. Additionally, in this case, the user doesn't have permission to edit the file themselves, so the "work around" doesn't work at all.

Sorry if someone else has asked this. I couldn't find a result when searching.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried creating a new file to save the new information before deleting the old one and renaming the new one?

Comment: @EvanBailey That sounds like it could work ... one question, could renaming fail? If not, I would gladly accept this as an answer if you posted it!

Comment: Do these files need to be used directly by any other applications or users? (i.e. is the exact file name important to anything but your own code?)

Comment: @EvanBailey No, the file is only accessible from the app (due to android's strict privacy on all the files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could ensure that you do not wipe the file is by creating a new file with a different name first. If writing that file succeeds, you could delete the old file and rename the new one.

There is the possibility that renaming fails. To be completely safe from that, your files could be named according to the time at which they are created. For instance, if your file is named `save.dat`, you could add the time at which the file was saved (from `System.currentTimeMillis()`) to the end of the file's name. Then, no matter what happens later (including failure to delete the old file or rename the new one), you can recover the most recent successful save. I have included a sample implementation below which represents the time as a 16-digit zero-padded hexadecimal number appended to the file extension. A file named `save.dat` will be instead saved as `save.dat00000171ed431353` or something similar.

```
// name includes the file extension (i.e. "save.dat").
static File fileToSave(File directory, String name) {
    return new File(directory, name + String.format("%016x", System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

// return the entire array if you need older versions for which deletion failed. This could be useful for attempting to purge any unnecessary older versions for instance.
static File fileToLoad(File directory, String name) {
    File[] files = directory.listFiles((dir, n) -> n.startsWith(name));
    Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparingLong((File file) -> Long.parseLong(file.getName().substring(name.length()), 16)).reversed());
    return files[0];
}
```